# Redirecting URLs that have 2nd url appended

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

According to our SEO person, we are getting traffic at URLs like so:

```
http://www.oursite.com/articles/article1/www.someothersite.com/page.aspx/sectionID%20=113/
```

I would like to 301 redirect to http://www.oursite.com/articles/article1 (remove the extra URL). Tried this in .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^http://www.oursite.com/articles/article1/www.someothersite.com/page.aspx/sectionID%20=113/$ /articles/article1
```

Which is not working...

Comment: What should `http://www.oursite.com/articles/article1/www.someothersite.com/page.aspx/sectionID%20=113/` be redirected to?

Comment: http://www.oursite.com/articles/article1

Answer (score 0):

You can use this redirect rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /(.+)/www\.someothersite\.com/.*$ /$1
```